# Calculate months between two dates and which months are (PHP)

Tags: php

I have two date inputs, I want to count the months between them and also know which months those are, for example:

If the first date input is 08/05/2020 and the second is 01/05/2021 I would like to have a function that outputs, 6 (six) and which months are covered, (08, 09, 10, 11, 12, 01).

I easily found the first part here on stackoverflow, but I can't figure the second. Could you give me a hand?

Answer (score 1):

You can just loop between the two dates one month at a time and append the result to an array.

```
$start = new DateTime('2020-08-05');
$end = new DateTime('2021-01-05');

$months = [];
while ($start <= $end) {
    $months[] = $start->format('Y-m');
    $start->modify('First day of +1 month');
}
        
print_r($months); // Array ( [0] => 2020-08 [1] => 2020-09 [2] => 2020-10 [3] => 2020-11 [4] => 2020-12 [5] => 2021-01 )
```

Then to get the number of months, just do `count($months)`.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, method showed by @[Mike` does exactly what you need, however, you should be also probably interested in some more advanced usage based on a sample from [SunilKmChard in the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php#115065). Probably you may combine both solutions to fetch best results.

```php
echo dateDifference(
    new DateTime('2000/01/25'),
    new DateTime('2010/02/20'),
    '%y Year %m Month %d Day'
);

function dateDifference($datetime1, $datetime2, $differenceFormat = '%a')
{
    $interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
    return $interval->format($differenceFormat);
}

// output: 10 Year 0 Month 26 Day
```

or other sample with `diff`

```
<?php

$start = new DateTime('2000/01/25');
$end = new DateTime('2010/02/20');

$interval = $end->diff($start);

$years = intval($interval->format('%y'));
$months = intval($interval->format('%m'));
$days = intval($interval->format('%d'));
$daysTotal = intval($interval->format('%a'));
$hoursTotal = $daysTotal * 24;
$minuteTotal = $hoursTotal * 60;
$secondsTotal = $minuteTotal * 60;

$totalMonthsDiff = ($years * 12) + $months;
echo "Difference is $years years, $months months and $days days, which in totals is:<br>
$years years<br>
or $totalMonthsDiff months<br> 
or $daysTotal days <br>
or $hoursTotal hours<br> 
or $minuteTotal minutes<br> 
or $secondsTotal seconds<br>";

/* Output
Difference is 10 years, 0 months and 26 days, which in totals is:
10 years
or 120 months
or 3679 days
or 88296 hours
or 5297760 minutes
or 317865600 seconds
 */
```